# How to show information without creating about 90 tables?

Tags: sql, qt, database-design

In my Qt C++ project I am using SQL database for table view. Everything is working fine, but now I need to create something bigger. I need to show name, school subject, and final assessment for this subject.

The problem is in that, that I've got about 45 subjects, and I need to repeat them twice cause there are 2 periods for each subject.

Do I need to create about 90 tables in SQL for each subject and each final assessment or is there some smarter and easier way?

Comment: what is the ER diagram of your database? Show the one which is working fine.

Comment: It seems to me that you need 90 entries in a single table, or multiple normalized tables

Comment: I've got one table from where i do get the names, and other table for the subject assessments, and i do combine them into one View, actually i need to create first the tables, then the views, to make all connection, i do not see any exit this this 90 table situation.

Comment: Thanks for your answers a lot. UmNyobe, maybe i can't get what do you mean but i think i really need to create all these tables. It will be tiring. Thanks again !

Comment: Please, stop working for a moment and read a few relational database and SQL tutorials. Your case seems to be quite simple and also a very common example subject in database tutorials. As erelender already said, you _do not_ need a separate table for every subject.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for your question is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model

Read carefully and you are going to find out that you don't need to create one table for each subject.